# How To Log Select Statements from 1 User On 1 Table Into a Permanent Log Table

Tags: sql-server, trigger, logs, audit

We have a centralized authentication library that 100+ applications use to authenticate users. That library has its own DB credentials. It would be extremely useful to log every time that library/user accesses a record in our software_user_permission table. I would want the log to exist not in a file but in a new permanent table.

What would be the best way to achieve this? or am I thinking in the wrong direction?

I want this to happen on the DB side without the library having to insert into the log table itself. Is this possible or commonly done with a trigger? What about a SQL Audit? The last thing I can think of is the library referring to a stored procedure that handles both the select and log statement.

Thanks!

Comment: There's no such thing as a trigger on a select statement. Auditing is possible (depending on version/edition), but an easier way would be to restrict data access to these users via stored procedures - then you can do whatever logging you want.